# Laravel Zizaco/Entrust role to allow owner to edit their own posts

Tags: laravel-5

I need to add permissions and roles to my application. Currently Laravel Authorization does not have this feature.

Using Zizaco/Entrust package https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust  you can create several roles with specific permissions which can be attached to a user based on role.

For example:
An administrator role allows users with administrator role to delete or modify a post.

My question is assuming I create a role called owner, how then can I determine that the current user making a request is an owner of a specific post and grant them permission to edit their own posts.

This example of how roles or permission can be checked when using this package.

```
$user->hasRole('owner'); 
$user->hasRole('admin'); 
$user->can('edit-user'); // false
```

How will this line of code below determine that the current user making an edit request is the owner of a post

```
$user->hasRole('owner');
```

I could not find any place in the package documentation where this was explained.

NB. This question is centered on Zizaco Entrust laravel package.

Comment: Have a similar requirement. Have you found an answer to this request elsewhere?

Comment: @FedericoStango not yet. But i will write my own implementation